# Spring 3.2 Validate Request Param, ControllerAdvice not formatting response

Tags: java, spring, validation

I'm using JSR 303 `@Valid` to validate multiple request params in a controller, the params posted along with a `MultipartFile`.

The validation part of this seems to be working,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
Response upload(@RequestParam(value = "file", required = true) MultipartFile file,
                @Valid ValidBean bean) {

    //method
}
```

`ValidBean` is a collection of Strings, Longs and a `List<String>`.

```
public class ValidBean{
   @NotNull
   String someString;

   @Size(min = 1, max=10)
   String anotherString;

   //getters, setters, random been goodness 


}
```

It seems that the client is getting rejected if the posted params do not match what is defined in `ValidBean`.

Where I am having an issue is with my global `@ControllerAdvice ValidationHandler`.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ValidationHandler {

@ExceptionHandler
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public @ResponseBody
StatusContext handleArgumentNotValid( MethodArgumentNotValidException error ){
    //format and return response 
}
```

My `@ExceptionHandler` only seems to be used in methods that use `@RequestBody @Valid`

So this method returns a formatted response,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/works", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
Formatted addUser(@RequestBody @Valid ValidBean user)
```

And this one does not,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/noGood", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
NotFormatted addUser(@Valid ValidBean user)
```

Though both do seem to actually perform validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody) for `@Valid @RequestBody` has this to say:

> Just like with @ModelAttribute parameters, an Errors argument can be
>   used to examine the errors. If such an argument is not declared, a
>   MethodArgumentNotValidException will be raised

that is the reason why your `@ExceptionHandler` with a method signature of `MethodArgumentNotValidException` gets called for `@Valid @RequestBody`.

On the other hand without `@RequestBody` but with `@Valid`, without an additional `BindingResult` parameter, a `BindException` gets generated, this will not be handled by the current specific signature of your `@ExceptionHandler`. The fix may be to make your `@ExceptionHandler` a little broader or add another `@ExceptionHandler` for BindException. Even better may be to just add `BindingResult` as an additional parameter.